# How to draw LineRenderer above other objects?

Tags: unity-game-engine

My line renderer is drawing behind objects. I want it to draw on top of other game objects except for the ball.

How can I do this?

See the following image to reference the problem (the line renderer draws below the goal, and I want it to draw itself on top.

[image]

I searched for the issue but haven't found a single answer for 3D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To render a material "above" some other materials, you must set your `LineRenderer` or `TrailRenderer`'s material `Rendering mode` to `Transparent`.

Also, set the `Rendering Mode` of materials of objects you wish to draw `LineRenderer` on top to `Transparent`.

Now go back to the `LineRenderer`'s material and in `Advanced Options` set its `Render Queue` to `3999`. (higher than the object's materials)

Now your `LineRenderer` will be drawn on top.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. But my goal is not that can you read my question again? My goal is to make linerenderer not to go on behind objects.

Comment: Could you phrase your question in a more clear way?

Comment: Wow you saved my day. Thank you for your clear and simple answer. Have a nice day!

Comment: You’re welcome and I’m glad I could help. Upvoting isn’t required but is greatly appreciated!